# Creating a applet in a web page

Tags: java, php, authentication, applet

I want to have a simple web page with fields for userName and password.Once a user enters the correct userName and password and press logIn button **then it should display an applet**. 
Here's my code.

```
<?php  
$un=$_POST["username"];  
$pw=$_POST["password"];  
$log=$_POST["Login"];  
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","");  
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con))  
    {  
    echo "Failed to connect".mysqli_connect_error();  
    }  
mysqli_select_db($con,student);  
$query="SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE stName=$un AND stP=$pw";  

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);  
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);  
if($log){  
    if($num_rows==1){  
    $isLogged=true;  
    }  
    else{  
    echo "Error log In.Invalid username or password";     
    $isLogged=false;  
    }  
}  
?>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>User LogIn</title>  
</head>  

<body>  
<form method="post">  
            <label>Username<input name="username" type="text" /></label> <label>Password<input name="password" type="password" /></label>  
            <input name="cmd" type="submit" value="Login" />  
        </form>  
<?php if($isLogged) {?>  
<applet code="studentWeb.html" width="32" height="32" alt="Couldn't launch applet" title="Student Details">  
</applet>  
<?php }?>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Right now it gives an error as

`mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in`
and it doesn't open up a applet even when correct username and password has been entered.

**Edit:** After I changed to action="logindata.php" in the form, here's the logindata.php

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
{
    echo "Failed to connect".mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_select_db($connect,"student") or die("couldn't connect to db");
$un=$_POST["username"];
$pw=$_POST["Password"];

$sql="SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE stUserName='$un' AND stPassword='pw'";

$query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die("couldn't find values");

if($query){
    include_once("studentWeb.html");
}
else{
echo ("Invalid username or password");

}


?>
```

Why does this **allow incorrect password and username** ?

Comment: Try debugging the applet loading in plain HTML (no log-in) to start with.  Also be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: `<applet code="studentWeb.html"..` that value should be a class name, rather than the name of a web page.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson My applet works fine without this logIn page.I changed it to<applet code="student.class">.I am not sure if the way I have implemented the login condition works correctly.Because I wrote `echo "Succesfully loggrd on ";` inside `if($log){  
    if($num_rows==1){  ` and it does't get printed. I have used `$log=$_POST["Login"];  ` to know if the logIn button has been pressed.Can I identify whether the login button is pressed from this way

Comment: @AndrewThompson  I corrected the mistake.I didn't have quotation marks inside `student` in `mysqli_select_db($con,student);  ` and wasn't even checking it.Also I add a` action=""` in the form and got rid of all the php part in index.Now after successful login it gives the applet but shows that  `Java needs permission to run on`

Comment: *"Now after successful login it gives the applet but.."*  Then you should accept an answer and ask a new question.  SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote these `WHERE stName='$un' AND stP='$pw'` since we're dealing with strings, which is why you are getting a boolean error.

Plus, use `isset()` around your executed code since you're using your entire code inside the same file.

You stand at getting an undefined index warning upon page entry.

Using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) will give you that:

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also  add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

---

**Footnotes:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

**Edit:**

If you wish to include a file (show contents of), do the following, which I am under the impression you wish to do:

```
<?php if($isLogged) { 

    include 'studentWeb.html';
}
?>
```

This is to be replaced by your present code:

```
<?php if($isLogged) {?>  
<applet code="studentWeb.html" width="32" height="32" alt="Couldn't launch applet" title="Student Details">  
</applet>  
<?php }?>
```

You can also try:

```
<?php $file = file_get_contents('studentWeb.html', true);
  echo $file;
?>
```

or `'../foldername/studentWeb.html'` depending on where the file is located.

---

The `<applet>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use the `<object>` tag instead if you are having problems with your present code. Yet, applets usually have the `.class` extension.

Consult **http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_applet_tag.htm**

---

**Edit #2:**

As per your edit, change:

```
if($query){
    include_once("studentWeb.html");
}
else{
echo ("Invalid username or password");

}
```

to:

```
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($numrows > 0){
   include_once("studentWeb.html");
}
```

Comment: @sam_rox You're very much welcome. I'm glad that a full solution came about. Always a pleasure. Edit: Seems the other messages were deleted, too many comments. Deleted by a moderator probably.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query()` is returning `false` because of failure.
Use `$query="SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE stName=" . $un . " AND stP= " . $pw;`
Moreover, this is not a good way because if your `query` fails, it will return boolean `false` which will again generate error for `mysqli_num_rows()`

You may look into [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) for further information and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php) for better ways to query your database.